# Django2.0で、ビューにアクセスしたら用意しておいたプログラム.pyを実行したい。

Tags: python, python3, django

Django2.0でアプリケーションを作成中です。
ブラウザで`localhost:8000/done`
というURLにアクセスしたら、`done.py`というpythonプログラムを実行するようにしたいです。
どのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import done

def done(request):
    print("viewのdoneが実行されています。")
    #done.Done_def()?ここに何を書いたらいいかがわからない
return render(request, 'done.html')
```

done.py

```
def Done_def():
    print("done.pyですよ")
```

urls.py

```
path('done', views.done, name='done'),
```

`localhost:8000/done`にアクセスすると、
コンソールには『viewのdoneが実行されています。』と出るようにはなります。
なのでviewにアクセスするところまでできているようですが、そこから『done.pyですよ』まで表示させたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そもそもの目的次第ですが、subprocessモジュールを使えば、いいと思います。

例)

```
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '/path/to/done.py'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdout_data, stderr_data = p.communicate()
print(stdout_data)
```

詳しい使い方は、[ここ](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/subprocess.html)を確認して下さい。

Comment: お早い回答ありがとうございます！subprocessを初めて聞いたので調べつつチャレンジしたところ、無事結果が表示されました！  ありがとうございました！

Comment: 解決したら、クローズしておいて下さい～